# Regex require backslash at end and a dash optional after last?

Tags: regex

I need to validate a string using regex where it allows any alphanumeric, ?s and backslashes, but there must always be one backslash at the end of the string and there can be an optional dash, but if the dash exists, the dash can only show up once anywhere after the last ? in the string.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Any ideas how could you think to solve it? Would you mind tagging a programming language or tool?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking at the following regex then:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\?\\]*(\?[a-zA-Z0-9\?\\]*-[a-zA-Z0-9\\]*)?\\$
```

Here is an example including the explanation of it: [RegExr](https://regexr.com/3pr6v).

Comment: if there is no `?` in the string, the regex doesn't give a match

Comment: Right, now the regex will match in case there is no dash specified in the string. I have modified it adding a "?" (the optional character identifier) after the dash character. The example is updated too.

Comment: I believe the requirement is to have one `-` after the `?`

Comment: quoting from the question itself "there can be an optional dash, but if the dash exists, the dash can only show up once anywhere after the last ? in the string".
If I understand the question, it means there can be only one occurrence of "-", anywhere after the last "?", correct? just want to make sure I do not misunderstand.

Comment: your understanding is same as mine. It still doesn't match `testexam09pleknaisjissadsnaiys\\`

Comment: right I see, if you add the string you mentioned as a new line it won't match: reason is related to "^" and "$" character. If you remove those from beginning and end of regex, then it will work; otherwise, if the regex should just match a line, you will see it working by placing only one line at a time in the example.
Depends what the exact use case is, which was not specified in the question.

Comment: it has nothing to do with `^` or `$`. the regex has `\?` which makes `?` mandatory for a match

Comment: right, good catch. I have updated the regex including your inputs, thanks. Now it should match any alphanumeric + "\" + "?" string where, if "-" is specified it must come anywhere after a "?" character.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex you're looking for:

`^[a-zA-Z0-9\?\\]*(?>\?-?)*[a-zA-Z0-9\?\\]*\\$`

I made you a permalink at rubular containing my regex, which can be found at:

http://rubular.com/r/gSSnfN8bwo

The examples who are highlighted in the 'match result' box are matches, those who are not, aren't.